# ANOVA parameter estimation

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, linear-regression, anova

I cannot find a formula for estimating coefficients ($a$ and $b$) of ANOVA model given by: $$\operatorname{weight} = a \cdot \operatorname{sex} + b + \epsilon$$
where $\operatorname{sex}=1$ means male and $\operatorname{sex}=0$ means female. The following table is provided

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{sex}& \text{amount} & \text{mean weight} & \text{std} \\ \hline
 \text{male} & 94 & 31.7 &2.62\\ \hline
\text{female}& 83 & 25.23&2.00\\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following process works generally if your independent variable is binary and you can assume the [usual assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions) for a linear regression.

Let $y = \text{weight}$ and $x = \text{sex}$. If you take an expectation of both sides conditioned on `sex`, you have:

$$ E[y | x = 0] = a*0 + b + E[\varepsilon | x = 0] , $$
$$ E[y | x = 1] = a*1 + b + E[\varepsilon | x = 1] . $$

If you assume $ E[\varepsilon | x ] = 0$ (exogeneity assumption of linear regression), then you have

$$ b = E[y | x = 0] , $$
$$ a = E[y | x = 1] - E[y | x = 0] . $$

Then, by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), a good estimator for the expectations is the relevant sample means:

$$ \hat{b} = \bar{y}_{x=0} , $$
$$ \hat{a} = \bar{y}_{x=1} - \bar{y}_{x=0} . $$

In other words, you can use the average weight of women as an estimator of $b$ and the difference in the average weight of men and women as an estimator of $a$.